# Bootstrap Datepicker unable to set start/end dates

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here is code:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="flight_start" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">

...

<script src="/ui/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/ui/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/ui/js/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ui/js/datatables/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/ui/js/responsive-tables/responsive-tables.js"></script>
<script src="/ui/js/datepicker/date.js"></script>
<script src="/ui/js/datepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/ui/js/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/ui/js/bootstrap-wizard/bootstrap-wizard.js"></script>
<script src="/ui/js/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ui/js/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"</script>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#flight_start').datepicker({
        format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
        startDate: "+1d"
    });
</script>
```

The format works, but not the start date. I get no errors/warnings, simply does not work. Dates prior to the start date are not grayed out in any way and can be selected. I want to remove this ability. Thanks!

Edit:
I've also tried

```
$('#flight_start').datepicker('setStartDate', '+1d');
```

Which gives me

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setStartDate'
```

Comment: What bootstrap datepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem was I had an out of date version of bootstrap-datepicker.js.

A coworker just picked up the plugin so I'm not sure why he downloaded an out of date version, oh well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code, worked for me. disabled dates prior to today

```
$("YOURSELECTOR").datepicker({
     format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
     startDate:new Date()
});
```

Remember this is bootstrap picker

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#flight_start').datepicker({
    format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
    startDate: "04-07-2010",
    endDate: "04-07-2014"
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Needs a document.ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#flight_start').datepicker({
        format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
        startDate: "+1d"
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No change I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 0):

I did like this, 
For end date

```
$("#yourDateFieldId").datepicker('setEndDate', (new Date().getDate())+"-"+(new Date().getMonth()+1)+"-"+new Date().getFullYear());
```

For start date

```
$("#yourDateFieldId").datepicker('setStartDate', "01-01-2000");
```